# MySQL query returning 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query but it return 0 rows.

What is the problem here ?

```
SELECT * FROM `banlist` 
WHERE `printscreen` IS NULL AND  `ip_address` LIKE '188.212%'
```

this is my table:

```
ID  DATE                      ip_address            prinscreen
___________________________________________________________________
62  2013-09-29 04:58:23      9.44.26.6:27015        <a href="http://>
61  2013-09-28 12:22:05      188.212.1.1:27015
```

Comment: you have to show your table with sample data

Comment: How we are supposed to solve your issue without your table and data descriptions ?

Comment: In that query there is no problem , just show your table data and we can see where is the problem

Comment: try empty check (printscreen = '') also in your query

Comment: I upvoted. It was a legit question asking where the slip-up occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `printscreen` is an empty string not null.

Try that

```
  SELECT * FROM `banlist` 
  WHERE (`printscreen` IS NULL Or `printscreen` = '')
  AND  `ip_address` LIKE '188.212%'
```

If your column printscreen is always have empty string then just use this

```
 SELECT * FROM `banlist` 
 WHERE `printscreen` = ''
 AND  `ip_address` LIKE '188.212%'
```

Comment: where can I do that ?

Comment: @user3297864 exact under the number 3 of my votes in the left , tick it to be green.thanks.and the upvote also are welcome :).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this.

```
SELECT * FROM banlist WHERE prinstscreen IS NULL AND ip_adress LIKE '188.212%'
```

But i'm think that `'188.212%'` isn't not right.

Comment: % is a wildcard in sql.  "188.212%" will find any entry which begins with "188.212".  NB - the downvote wasn't from me

Comment: i didn't mean to % :)